# Getting #VALUE error in SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-2013, sumifs

I have this simple table:

```
    A       B
1   Fruits  Amount
2   Apple   2
3   Orange  3
4   Banana  5
```

I do:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B4,A2:A4,"Apple", A2:A4, "Orange")
```

It returns `0`. If I erase either `A3:A5, "Apple"` or `A3:A5, "Orange"`, it works. What's wrong?

Comment: Saw your edit, but SUMIFS is not an array formula and therefore having full column References does it no harm.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work, issues a warning about a circular reference

Comment: So you have this formula in Column B and have `Apple` or `Orange` in Column A in the same row?  That is the only way you would get a circular reference.  Feel free to limit the range if that is the case.

Comment: Silly me, I put the formula in column A...Works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMIFS() uses `AND` not `OR`  so it is looking for one cell that is both Apple and Orange.

Use this instead:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,{"Apple","Orange"}))
```